# Did a new 'hash' get created

Tags: perl, hash

Here is some tests that I setup to help me understand hashes and references:

```
my %record1 = ( "Name"    => "My Name");
my %record2 = %record1;
my $record3 = \%record1;
$record1{'test'}= "yes";
print \%record1 ;
print "\n";
print %record1;
print "\n";
print \%record2;
print "\n";
print %record2;
print "\n";
print %$record3;
```

- record2 is a 'shallow' copy of record1?
- record3 is a hash ref (pointer) to record1?

and

```
sub some_func{
    %some_hash = ();
...
    return %some_hash;
}
%some_hash2 = some_func(); # created new hash? 

sub some_func2{
    %some_hash = ();
...
    return \%some_hash
}
$some_hash_ref3 = some_func2(); # ref to original hash?
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: In your subs the data structures are not lexical. That might make a difference to what you are seeing (or want to see, which I don't really know). Also just printing a hash variable probably doesn't do what you think. You should use Data::Dumper or Data::Printer to inspect your data structures.

Comment: Always put ***`use strict;`*** and ***`use warnings;`*** at the top your script. ***`use diagnostics;`*** may help you make sense of the errors and warnings you get. Without `strict` and `warnings`, you are bound to get yourself into confusing situations.

Answer (score 1):

First:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Scalar::Util qw( refaddr );

my %record1 = ("Name" => "My Name");

printf "Address of %%record1 = %d\n", refaddr \%record1;

my %record2 = %record1;

printf "Address of %%record2 = %d\n", refaddr \%record2;

my $record3 = \%record1;

printf "Address of hash pointed to by \$record3 = %d\n", refaddr $record3;
```

Output:

```
Address of %record1 = 140595226123056
Address of %record2 = 140595226215352
Address of hash pointed to by $record3 = 140595226123056
```

This shows that `%record1` and `%record2` are different hashes, whereas `$record3` points to `%record1`.

Next,

```
sub some_func{
    %record1 = ();
    return %record1
}
%record2 = some_func(); # created new hash?
```

Ouch! You are clearing the `%record1` hash (that is, removing all keys and values from it). `%record1` exists outside of this function. The only thing this function returns is an empty list.

Then `%record2 = some_func()` does two things: In the body of the function, it clears `%record1`. And, because it returns the empty list, it also clears all the keys and values from `%record2`.

Now, add

```
printf "Address of %%record1 = %d\n", refaddr \%record1;

printf "Address of %%record2 = %d\n", refaddr \%record2;
```

After `%record2 = some_func()`, and you'll see that `%record1` and `%record2` are still the same hashes. However, they are both empty:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper $_ for \(%record1, %record2);
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {};
$VAR1 = {};
```

Finally, turning our attention to:

```
$record3 = some_func(); # ref to original hash?
```

We already established that `some_func` returns the empty list. However, because you are assigning the return value to a scalar, you are imposing scalar context on the returned list. `$record3` will get the last element in the returned list, not the number of elements in the returned list. In this case, that will be `undef` as there are no elements in the returned list. And in numeric contexts, that undef will be interpreted as `0`. (thanks to David Cross for catching my array/list confusion).

`$record3` is no longer a reference to anything.

Comment: *`$record3` will be assigned the number of elements in the returned list* - No. `$record3` will get the last element in the returned list, not the number of elements in the returned list. In this case, that will be `undef` as there are no elements in the returned list. And in numeric contexts, that `undef` will be interpreted as 0.

Comment: @DaveCross Corrected. Thanks for catching my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

> *record2 is a 'shallow' copy of record1?*

Yes, `%record1` and `%record2` are distinct hashes, and `%record2` contains a (shallow) copy of the contents of `%record1`.

> *record3 is a hash ref (pointer) to record1?*

Yes, `$record3` contains a reference to the hash `%record1`.

```
$ perl -e'
   my %record1 = ( "Name" => "My Name");
   my %record2 = %record1;
   my $record3 = \%record1;
   CORE::say( \%record1 == \%record2 ? "same" : "different" );
   CORE::say( \%record1 == $record3  ? "same" : "different" );
'
different
same
```

Note that while references and pointers are very similar, they aren't the same thing. A reference is a pointer on which you can't perform arithmetic. Perl only has references.

> *created new hash?*

No. `my` creates new variables, and you didn't use `my`. Undeclared variables such as `%some_hash` are created when a reference to them is first encountered (and thus at compile-time instead of during the call to `some_func`).

Furthermore, `some_func` didn't return a hash. It's impossible to return anything but scalars from a sub. (Also, it's impossible to pass anything but scalars to a sub.) `some_func` in fact returns the *contents* of `%record1`, which is an empty list in this case.

> *ref to original hash?*

Yes. The returned scalar (a reference to `%some_hash`) is copied into `$some_hash_ref3`, so `$some_hash_ref3` then contains a reference to `%some_hash`.